# Box2D and Cocos2d-x coordinates

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm using Box2D and cocos2d-x but I can't figure the coordinate system out.

I know cocos2d-x uses `P(0,0)` as the bottom left part of the screen.
And Box2D uses `P(0, 0)` as the center of it's world.

I'm using debug draw for Box2D.

When creating a body with a polygon shape attached to it at `P(0,0)` in Box2D coordinates it shows up on the bottom left part of the screen.

Why doesn't it show up in the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When positioning any `b2Body`, use `Sprite::getBoundingBox().getMidX()` for the horizontal center, and for the vertical center use `Sprite::getBoundingBox().getMidY()`.

You might want to wrap those calls in a `Node::convertToWorldSpace(midX, midY)` to make sure that your center coordinates are expanded into the cocos2d-x world coordinate system and hence the Box2D world coordinate space as it has to be consistent.